# Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition (PC) Audio is not workin

Tags: pc, dark-souls

The in-game audio is not working at all, no music in the menus, no effects or nothing while playing (Microsoft Live sound does work, though).

This is the environment:

- Steam client
- Windows 8 64 bits
- ASUS P7P55D integrated sound card for audio

The sound card is connected to a receiver through SPDIF. Everything else works without a problem, both in 5.1 (movies) and stereo (music and games). I do not use AC3 or any encoder for 5.1 gaming. All of the other games I have do not have any sound issue. I have also tried to connect headphones to the corresponding jack in the sound card with the same bad result.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows audio mixer? Right-click the speak icon in your taskbar.

Comment: Is just Dark Souls sound not working, or any sound at all?

Comment: I have checked everything and looked for answers here and other places, but I didn't find anything. The audio mixer doesn't show activity coming from the game. I also tried connecting headphones to the headphone output in the sound card.

Comment: Voting for a reopen. I don't get what is unclear about the question. I suppose Microsoft Windows Live is working, because it is a different application.

Comment: Also, check this thread out: http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900321

Comment: Thanks, Bora. My initial one was not so well explained, sorry about that. I'll reinstall and if doesn't work I'll also go through the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It seems that I didn't realize, but actually the AC3 encoder was starting alongside the game and not processing the audio properly. I disabled the AC3 encoder to process PCM and now it works, although now AAC audio won't work with my player. At least now I have something.